Azure HTTP function route
I'm trying to convert flask API to azure functions.
@app.route(route="{directory_name}/static/{file_path:path}", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS,
           methods=[func.HttpMethod.GET])
def serve_static(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    ....

In flask, the route with {file_path:path} works but in azure function I'm getting this error:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing: An error occurred while creating the route with name 'serve_static' and template
'{directory_name}/static/{file_path:path}'. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing: The constraint entry 'file_path' - 'path' on the route '{directory_name}/static/{file_path:path}' could not be resolved by the constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver'.

I looked for something similar but I cant seem to find something helpful.

The issue you're facing is that Azure Functions HTTP triggers don’t support custom route patterns like  {file_path:path}  the way Flask does. Instead, you’ll need to create a route and then handle parsing the URL yourself within your function.
Below is the HTTP trigger function to create a route and handle parsing the URL within the function.
serve_static/init.py :
import azure.functions as func
from urllib.parse import unquote
import os

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    directory_name = req.route_params.get('directory_name')
    file_path = req.route_params.get('file_path', '')
    file_path = unquote(file_path)  
    
    static_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
    full_path = os.path.join(static_folder, directory_name, file_path)
    
    if not os.path.commonprefix([static_folder, full_path]) == static_folder:
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid file path", status_code=400)
    
    try:
        with open(full_path, 'rb') as f:
            file_content = f.read()
        return func.HttpResponse(file_content, mimetype="application/octet-stream")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return func.HttpResponse(f'File not found: {full_path}', status_code=404)  
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f'Error: {str(e)}', status_code=500)

serve_static/function.json :
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "{directory_name}/static/{*file_path}",
      "methods": ["get"]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}

Browser Output :
I have downloaded the example.txt file with the HTTP trigger function URL as below,
http://localhost:7071/api/docs/static/example.txt


Terminal Output :
The following HTTP trigger function code ran successfully as below.

Below is the data inside my example.txt file.


Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
